# "Can't compress a recycled bitmap" - but I don't use any Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm getting error "*Can't compress a recycled bitmap*", but in my app I don't use bitmaps (not directly). I have only logo on main screen, and one icon, from drawables (*.png files), but I also use AdMob ads (maybe this is the cause).

Problem occurred not on my phone (Android v: 4.1.2), so I have limited details about that, below is stack trace:

```
0 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
1   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
2   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
3   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
4   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
5   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
6   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
7   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
8   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
9   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap
11  at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:239)
12  at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:764)
13  at com.instabug.library.internal.storage.r.a(SaveBitmapTask.java:43)
14  at com.instabug.library.internal.storage.r.doInBackground(SaveBitmapTask.java:17)
15  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
16  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
17  ... 5 more
```

Can I sand any more informations about it?
Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: The issue is occurring in the Instabug library. That said most images originate from the `Bitmap` class.

Comment: what do you think happens when you try to display a png file? (answer: it is decompressed into a bitmap)

Comment: Most likely it was a fault of Instabug, thanks @CoryCharlton